# How to set the Button text programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I know how to change the button text programmatically in iOS:

```
[myButton setTitle:@"myTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but my need is I have a label called _lblgenisis, I put some code to change the text of this label and it works fine for me, the code for that is:

```
_lblGenisis.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",delegate.selectedBook,delegate.selectedChapter];
```

my requirement is I have to convert to this code to show the same in button instead of label my button name is _btnGenisis. How to do this?

---

## Solution

Answer that works for me:

```
NSString *myTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",delegate.selectedBook,delegate.selectedChapter];
[nextButton setTitle:myTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I get this right.

The code that normally works for changing your button label is not working to set it programmatically?

I have had this issue it turns out that:
When you set the label in the xib file you can see the results and won't make any mistakes.  Recently I had a custom button with an image and couldn't figure out why I could not add a title programmatically.
It turns out I was setting the title properly (the way you already know how to). The real issue was that I set my button's image with `setImage:forState`.  This image is above the button and you should check your xib file to see if you have an image set for the button.  If so, delete the image and set it as the background image.

To see if this is actually the issue, try this in your code where you are trying to set the title

```
NSLog(@"image for button %@", _btnGenisis.currentImage);
```

It should output (null)
If it outputs like  you have an image covering your button's title.
Check the interface file and inspect the button.  Make sure there is no default image set.  You can set a default background image.
If it is all created in code do a search for
 `[_btnGenisis setImage:`
You should not be setting the image if you want a title.  Use

```
[_btnGenesis setBackgroundImage:yourTitleHere forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the label to the button?

`[_btnGenisis addSubview:_lblGenisis]`

Comment: i added the label in iboutlet,is that the problem ?